# deep learning specialization corsera the regularization exercise when i run the helping cod to get started it shows the following error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

let's first import the packages you are going to use.

```
# import packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from reg_utils import sigmoid, relu, plot_decision_boundary, initialize_parameters, load_2D_dataset, predict_dec
from reg_utils import compute_cost, predict, forward_propagation, backward_propagation, update_parameters
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import scipy.io
from testCases import *

%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (7.0, 4.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'
# import packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from reg_utils import sigmoid, relu, plot_decision_boundary, initialize_parameters, load_2D_dataset, predict_dec
from reg_utils import compute_cost, predict, forward_propagation, backward_propagation, update_parameters
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import scipy.io
from testCases import *
​
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (7.0, 4.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'


train_X, train_Y, test_X, test_Y = load_2D_dataset()
```

so when i ran the above cod ii shows the following error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 train_X, train_Y, test_X, test_Y = load_2D_dataset()

```
~\Desktop\specializtion\hayper tununig\week5\Regularization\reg_utils.py in load_2D_dataset()
    326 
    327 def load_2D_dataset():
--> 328     data = scipy.io.loadmat('datasets/data.mat')
    329     train_X = data['X'].T
    330     train_Y = data['y'].T

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py in loadmat(file_name, mdict, appendmat, **kwargs)
    215     variable_names = kwargs.pop('variable_names', None)
    216     with _open_file_context(file_name, appendmat) as f:
--> 217         MR, _ = mat_reader_factory(f, **kwargs)
    218         matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
    219 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py in mat_reader_factory(file_name, appendmat, **kwargs)
     70     """
     71     byte_stream, file_opened = _open_file(file_name, appendmat)
---> 72     mjv, mnv = get_matfile_version(byte_stream)
     73     if mjv == 0:
     74         return MatFile4Reader(byte_stream, **kwargs), file_opened

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\miobase.py in get_matfile_version(fileobj)
    233     tst_str = fileobj.read(4)
    234     fileobj.seek(0)
--> 235     maj_ind = int(tst_str[2] == b'I'[0])
    236     maj_val = byteord(tst_str[maj_ind])
    237     min_val = byteord(tst_str[1-maj_ind])`enter code here`

`
`IndexError: index out of range


----------
```